# Can I run a shell script located on /boot just by modifying other files on /boot?

Tags: raspbian, boot

I've created a shell script that is setting up things for me and my colleagues. This script is the first thing to be run on a clean Rasbian installation.

Problems:

- at this time, the keyboard is not configured correctly, so even the simple task of running the script becomes difficult, because we don't find the special keys to enter `/` in the shell
- it's easy to forget running the script

Therefore I'm looking for a way to run the script automatically at second startup (at first startup, Raspbian will resize the partition).

Since we're totally Windows-based, I only have access to /boot and I can modify files there only. Is it possible to run it with these limitations?

Other options like mounting in a VM or booting the Pi and modifying other files are just not convenient enough, so it won't be used.

Comment: re problem one, print a cheatsheet for your developers, that's no excuse ;) Hint: / is on the key labelled "-", the one next to the right shift key. WRT the second issue, I have the feeling that has been asked before.

Comment: If there's a technical solution I prefer it over an organizational solution.

Comment: Check this out http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/use-boot-cmdline-txt-for-creating-first-boot-script/44950#44950

Comment: I would have closed as duplicate myself after my edit were approved. Seems I'm a second too late...