# Boot Partition "Run Once" Headless Script

Tags: boot

To setup SSH and Wi-Fi connectivity before even booting up a Pi for the first time, one can put files into the boot partition on the SD card.

This has me curious. Suppose I have a particular setup I want to have on all of my new Raspberry Pis. Is there a way I can add scripts to this same boot partition that are run when the Pi boots up for the first them, but never again?

Comment: Yes. burn a fresh image. Prevent that image from expanding the filesystem on first boot. Add your logic for running this script (see how ssh/wifi is done and do something similar) - create an image from the sd card (after re-enabling the expand on first boot)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use /boot/cmdline.txt for creating first-boot script](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/use-boot-cmdline-txt-for-creating-first-boot-script). Look at the accepted answer pointing to github.